# React/NextJS integration of WeatherWidget.io

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to integrate [WeatherWidget.io](https://weatherwidget.io/) into a React/NextJS app.

This isn't a react component, and in order to integrate it you have to copy paste a `<a>` and a `<script>` tag.

By using the NextJS `<Head>` component (equivalent to ReactHelmet), it renders properly server side, however, once the first client side update is triggered, the component disappears.

I've tried using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, or manually creating a script tag in `ComponentDidMount`, but it didn't work.

Do you have any best practice for this scenario? I've also tried to avoid the component to re-render, but setting `shouldComponentUpdate` to false doesn't work either (I would have to get to Component completely out of the render tree, and it's not possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Place the `script` tag of the widget at the bottom of your HTML page.
2. Place the `a` tag in a component.

Comment: Are you able to show the code sample? It has some errors while integrating the html code to React app.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get the weather widget using React pure components.
Try something like this.

```
export class WeatherWidget extends PureComponent {

render() {
    return (
        <div className={this.props.className || ""}>
            <a className="weatherwidget-io" href="https:forecast7.com/es/n24d78n65d42/salta/" data-label_1="SALTA" data-label_2="CAPITAL" data-theme="original" >SALTA CAPITAL</a>

            {!function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                // if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = 'https:weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                // }
            }
                (document, 'script', 'weatherwidget-io-js')
            }

        </div>
    )
}};
```

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I had to use useEffect as follows:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function GetWeather() {
  useEffect(() => {
    !(function (d, s, id) {
      var js,
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }
    })(document, "script", "weatherwidget-io-js");
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="weather">
      <a
        className="weatherwidget-io"
        href="https://forecast7.com/en/41d28n73d50/ridgefield/?unit=us"
        data-label_1="RIDGEFIELD"
        data-label_2="WEATHER"
        data-days="3"
        data-theme="pure"
      >
        RIDGEFIELD WEATHER
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, but when i try to add this code in nextjs with some changes it show nothing